# Set Date automaticallly

Tags: android, date

I would add a record field in my form that will tell the user to set the date of registration in the pane "set date" and then after that it fills the time, 365 days is automatically added to the component "Date of end registration" without it can not change the second part. It can only change the first flying "date of registration". How could I do it in java and xml? thank you kindly help me friends.
PS: Look this pic to have an idea of what I want

[image]

Comment: You can use [JodaDateTime API, addDays(365)](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#plusDays(int)) method.

Comment: Please show an exemple to facilitate my understanding. If possible the source code for I am a beginner. Thanks @UmaKanth

Answer (score 0):

First retrieve the date from the date of registration textbox, using below code:

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
 String dateInString = dateofreg.getText().toString();
    Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
```

After retrieving it set in the date of end registration textbox.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();    
c.setTime(date);
c.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
dateOfEndreg.setText(formatter.format(c.getTime());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! What field should I insert into the xml part? I know there are "TextView" and the date? What added element ? @Psypher

Comment: You should insert a Textview and edittext. Textview for the label and the edittext to collect the date.

Comment: Ok I see. But how to insert bars for the date (dd / mm / yyyy) in the "EditText" like so that when you click adds the date following the date of symbols? @Psypher

Comment: In the simpletDateFormat, change to `SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy")`..i have updated the answer

Comment: I tried but I can not. there are errors. It emphasizes "formatter.parse (dateInString)" and "dateofreg". PLEASE sacrifices at least 5 minutes to write me all the java code into position and that of xml. I am a beginner. really sorry you ask that, but I really want to solve my problem @Psypher

Comment: Please dear, help me @Psypher